# Modify foot and toe rigify human meta-rig

Tags: rigify

How can I modify the 'foot.' bones and 'toe.' bones of human (meta-rig)? There will be an error while generate rig if those bones being deleted, or when the 'toe.' bones become parents of other bones?

Comment: What kind of modification do you want?  You can always modify the generated rig. Will that work?

Comment: I want to keep the legs and foot_ik. widget, but add some more bones to the 'toe.', or maybe replace the 'foot.' chains.